# Preloading animated images on Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Is there some way to force Firefox to preload the animated image file (GIFs, for example) before playing them so that I have a still shot of the first frame until the browser downloads the whole file and then it plays it nice and smoothly instead of this terrible flickering as if it were 1 frame per 2 seconds until the whole thing loads? That's how iPad's Safari deals with the GIFs, for example.

Comment: I didn't know that Firefox had any problem with that. I use Firefox all the time, and animated GIF's play fine. Maybe your Firefox is too old? Maybe you have an ancient graphics card?

Comment: @BenjiWiebe: Try a huge GIF (say 5-10 MB or so) on a slow connection if you want to know what he's talking about. :) FF will load and display the frames incrementally, whereas he wants it to display just the first frame and load the rest in the background, then start playing *only* when the entire file is available locally.

Comment: Just as Karan said :)